# Characteristic polynomial of an involution

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm attempting to prove that the characteristic polynomial of an involution in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. a linear transformation that satisfies $f^2=I$ will always factor into linear factors.

We know that $p_{f^2}(\lambda)=(1-\lambda)^n$ where $p_f$ is the characteristic polynomial of the linear operator $f$. That's as far as I've gotten with useful thoughts (except a dozen of dead ends).

After some contemplation, I've tried googling the problem and found out all of the proofs are using the *minimal polynomial*, which hasn't been introduced in my course, therefore I'm guessing there is some more elementary way to prove this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose not. Then the characteristic polynomial $p_f(x)$ of $f$ will contain an irreducible factor of degree at least $2$, and hence $p_f(x)$ will have a non-real complex root $\lambda$. So, viewing $f$ now as an element of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, let $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ be a non-zero eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$. What is $f^2 v$?

Comment: Thanks! So ${\lambda}^2=1$ thus $\lambda$ cannot have an imaginary part, is that correct?

Comment: The only square roots of unity are $1$ and $-1$, so...

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

$(A-\lambda I)(A+\lambda I)=(1-\lambda^2) I$. Hence $\det(A-\lambda I)$ divides 
$\det((1-\lambda^2) I) = (1-\lambda^2)^n$.

Comment: This is very nice.

Comment: Indeed, this is beautiful! Hope one day I'll be coming up with answers like this myself.

Comment: @Branimir Ćaćić: Thank you/Hvala

Answer (score 1):

Since $f^2=I$ it follows that the **minimal** polynomial of $f$ is $x-1$ or $x+1$ or $(x-1)(x+1)$.
 
The **characteristic** polynomial of $f$ has the same roots as the minimal polynomial of $f$. Therefore it factors into linear terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without mentioning the minimal polynomial, although morally the argument below is the same as the one (given in another answer) that does.

If $v$ is an eigenvector of (the complexified) $f$ with (complex) eigenvalue$~\lambda$, then $f^k(v)=\lambda^kv$, and so by linearity $P(f)(v)=P(\lambda)v$ for any polynomial $P$. This implies that any polynomial equation satisfied by $f$ must also be satisfied by$~\lambda$; in the case $f^2=I$ implies that $\lambda^2=1$ for all eigenvalues$~\lambda$. This means that all (complex) roots of the characteristic polynomial are roots of $X^2-1$, and these roots are $+1,-1$, both real. Since a characteristic polynomial always splits over the complex numbers, this $p_f$ splits over the reals too.